# iOS UnitySendMessage call parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I am writing the Objective-C part of a Unity project. In AppController.mm, I declared

```
extern void UnitySendMessage(const char *, const char *, const char *);
```

And I am calling this like,

```
- (void)callUnityObject:(const char*)object Method:(const char*)method Parameter:(const char*)parameter
{
    UnitySendMessage(object, method, parameter);
}
```

But I have a Unity function that has to receive an int parameter.
So, if I call like this:

```
[self callUnityObject:"_iosManager" Method:"GiveDynamite" Parameter:"50"];
```

The app doesn't crash, but the call doesn't work and I am getting an output like this:

> The best match for method GiveDynamite has some invalid parameter.

If I call like this:

```
[self callUnityObject:"_iosManager" Method:"GiveDynamite" Parameter:50];
```

The App is crashing.

How can I send this message from Objective-c to Unity?

I tried declaring a new method like this:

```
extern void UnitySendMessage(const char *, const char *, int);
```

But the app crashed and said that unity doesn't have a function declaration like that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need to redeclare UnitySendMessage, it already is in iPhone_target_Prefix.pch. do you have a GameObject called "_iosManager" with a script having a method `void GiveDynamite (string amount)`

Comment: I solved it like the answer above. I have the method, I figured out that I can only send char value to _iosManager object. I parsed that char as int in the Unity part, not in the Xcode.

Comment: Where do I write this code " extern void UnitySendMessage(constchar *, constchar *, constchar *); " when I wrote this at the top, below the import functions I got a error message "Unknown type name 'constchar' "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to:

```
void UnitySendMessage( const char * className, const char * methodName, const char * param )
```

You should pass `char*`:

```
[self callUnityObject:"_iosManager" Method:"GiveDynamite" Parameter:"50"];
```

On Unity class you should receive "string" param

```
void GiveDynamite(string dinamite) {
...
}
```

and then parse it to integer value, f.e:

```
dinamiteAmount = int.Parse(dinamite);
```